# Is there any overhead in massively using .? operators for field/property comparisons?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-core, operator-overloading

If we have 2 objects and we've overloaded an equality operator to compare each one, should we be weary of the usage of the ? operator (for example `firstObject?.MyProperty == secondObject?.MyProperty`) if we end up using that on say 20-30 properties?

Basically for large objects with lots of properties, is it better to do the following comparison

```
(firstObject == null && secondObject == null || !(firstObject == null ^ secondObject == null)) 
&&  (<property comparisons without ?>)
```

or simply

`<property comparisons with ?>`

Thank you.

Comment: When you loaded it into a loop that did a billion equality checks, what were the results of the performance test?

Comment: If you have a lot of fields, it's more clean to check the entire object for `null` first and avoid repeating of the code

Comment: There is no better, because you gave no domain in which something can be better. Null conditional will generate more IL, however looks neater. Yet the both do the same thing. When all is said and done, any difference in performance could well be optimized away

Comment: @CaiusJard with ? operator comparisons I got 00:03:57.3792339, without ? it's 00:03:48.5972988 (ran on Release, without debugging). Not sure if the difference is real or not, but it doesn't seem to impact a lot.

Comment: I guess then it comes down to a question of "how many hours/days/years will it be before the production system has done a billion legitimate compares, and is the 9 seconds saved gong to be worth it versus the cleanliness of the code..". If prod does a billion compares an hour, it could represent a reasonable saving; if it'l  e a year of operation before that compare count is hit it's not worth the ugliness (IMHO)

Comment: @TheGeneral Null-conditional (aka "Elvis operator") generates *less* IL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood they are **different**. The `?.` is more readable and **faster** (it seems).

### Proof

First, consider this sample (targeting `.NET Framework 4.7.2`):

```
class Program
{
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo Bar { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        var t0 = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            UsingElvisOperator(foo);
            // UsingIfsAndButs(foo);
        }
        var t1 = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;

        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time: {(t1 - t0) / 10000} ms");
    }

    private static void UsingIfsAndButs(Foo foo)
    {
        if (foo?.Bar?.Bar?.Bar != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        }
    }

    private static void UsingElvisOperator(Foo foo)
    {
        if (foo != null && foo.Bar != null && foo.Bar.Bar != null && foo.Bar.Bar.Bar != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Compile it in `Release` mode for `Any CPU` platform. Now let's decompile the produced `.exe` using [ildasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler).

The instructions for the **Elvis operator**:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  UsingElvisOperator(class OperatorTest.Program/Foo foo) cil managed
{
  // Code size       53 (0x35)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  brfalse.s  IL_0034
  IL_0003:  ldarg.0
  IL_0004:  callvirt   instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_0009:  brfalse.s  IL_0034
  IL_000b:  ldarg.0
  IL_000c:  callvirt   instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_0011:  callvirt   instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_0016:  brfalse.s  IL_0034
  IL_0018:  ldarg.0
  IL_0019:  callvirt   instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_001e:  callvirt   instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_0023:  callvirt   instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_0028:  brfalse.s  IL_0034
  IL_002a:  ldstr      "OK"
  IL_002f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0034:  ret
} // end of method Program::UsingElvisOperator
```

And the instructions for the **if-checks**:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  UsingIfsAndButs(class OperatorTest.Program/Foo foo) cil managed
{
  // Code size       49 (0x31)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  brtrue.s   IL_0006
  IL_0003:  ldnull
  IL_0004:  br.s       IL_0024
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  IL_0007:  call       instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_000c:  dup
  IL_000d:  brtrue.s   IL_0013
  IL_000f:  pop
  IL_0010:  ldnull
  IL_0011:  br.s       IL_0024
  IL_0013:  call       instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_0018:  dup
  IL_0019:  brtrue.s   IL_001f
  IL_001b:  pop
  IL_001c:  ldnull
  IL_001d:  br.s       IL_0024
  IL_001f:  call       instance class OperatorTest.Program/Foo OperatorTest.Program/Foo::get_Bar()
  IL_0024:  brfalse.s  IL_0030
  IL_0026:  ldstr      "OK"
  IL_002b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0030:  ret
} // end of method Program::UsingIfsAndButs
```

Clearly, the generated instructions are different.

### Performance comparison

Running the two methods **one billion** times, on my machine, gives me the following results:

```
UsingElvisOperator:   1704 ms
UsingIfsAndButs:      2815 ms
```

Comment: Its important to note though, you actually didn't benchmark the ops question. oops. anyway, plus one for the effort, and i would always use the null conditional myself regardless

Comment: @TheGeneral You're right. I don't fully understand the OP, so I did some creative interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

just want to share my benchmarking summy which checks either the null and non null test object, which shows an advantage in speed for the "ifs":

```
// * Summary *
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.18363.900 (1909/November2018Update/19H2)
Intel Core i5-7300U CPU 2.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 4 logical and 2 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.301

  [Host] : .NET Core 3.1.5 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.26901, CoreFX 4.700.20.27001), X64 RyuJIT

Job=NewJob  IterationCount=2  LaunchCount=2  
RunStrategy=Throughput  WarmupCount=1  

|             Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|
------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
|    UsingIfsAndButs | 1.518 ns | 0.4293 ns | 0.0664 ns |
| UsingElvisOperator | 2.144 ns | 0.2124 ns | 0.0329 ns |
```

and the code:

```
[SimpleJob(RunStrategy.Throughput, launchCount: 2, warmupCount: 1, targetCount: 2, id: "NewJob")]
public class ElvisBenchmarks
{
    Foo foo;
    Foo foo_null;
    Boolean isNull;
    
    public ElvisBenchmarks()
    {
         foo = new Foo();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingIfsAndButs()
    {
        isNull = (foo != null && foo.Bar != null && foo.Bar.Bar != null && foo.Bar.Bar.Bar != null)
                ? true : false;

        isNull = (foo_null != null && foo_null.Bar != null && foo_null.Bar.Bar != null && foo_null.Bar.Bar.Bar != null)
                ? true : false;
    }
        
    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingElvisOperator()
    {
        isNull = (foo?.Bar?.Bar?.Bar != null) ? true : false;
        isNull = (foo_null?.Bar?.Bar?.Bar != null) ? true : false;
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public Foo Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... any theories as to why this happens? If you test not nested Foo's but properties of foo, I think the result will be the opposite.